# using existing github repository in my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, combobox

I've been searching for awhile for a good combobox for a Rails app.

I found this one:
https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/tree/1.1.1 and it is exactly what I am looking for. I just can't figure out how to make it work in Rails. I have a micropost that has a :receiver so that when it is submitted the post is preceded by an acronym for who the post is meant for.

I've added the bootstrap-combobox.js and the bootstrap-typeahead.js to assets/javascripts.
I've included the .css file.  And I have inserted the code:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @micropost %> 
  <div class="field">
    <div id="post_form">                
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose..." %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">

      <%= f.select  :receiver,
      [['all', 'all'],
      ['aicc', 'aicc'],
      ['daf', 'daf'],
      ['faf', 'faf'],
      ['gal', 'gal'],
      ['mcg', 'mcg'],
      ['paq', 'paq'],
      ['self', 'self'],
      ['uyt', 'uty']],
      :class =>"combobox"%> 
     </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.combobox').combobox();
   });
 </script>
```

I am getting the combobox as described and it works except that when I submit the form it always sends the first value, "all", no matter which value I select or what I enter into the field.  I've made some changes recommended by the plugin author but I am still getting the same results.

I have also tried to set it up with this code in the partial:

```
 <f.select> 
  <option></option>
  <option value="self">self</option>
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="aicc">aicc</option>
  <option value="daf">daf</option>
  <option value="faf">faf</option>
  <option value="gal">gal</option>
  <option value="kks">kks</option>
  <option value="mcg">mcg</option>
  <option value="paq">paq</option>
  <option value="tan">tan</option>
  <option value="tas">tas</option>
  <option value="uyt">uyt</option>
</select>
```

But I can not figure out how to retrieve the value with this format. Does anyone have any ideas of what I might do to make this work? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to specify the exact problem you're having. The "It won't work"-style questions don't get much positive attention. Having said that, it appears to be purely javascript based, so the only connection it might have with rails is whatever data is being passed to it. I might recommend something like the Gon gem for handing any Rails-to-javascript stuff.

Comment: Also you can get a brief about bootstrap - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll refresh on bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with rails as it is a HTML component. To use it, you have to put it in the presentation and retrieve the value as a regular combobox.